# mvc4future unable use in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I was downloaded Mvc4Future nuget package in my ASP.NET MVC 5 project.  When I use the ActionFilter attributes such as [AjaxOnly] will cause "Inheritance security rules violated by type" exception.  Here is the full message:

> Inheritance security rules violated by type: 'Microsoft.Web.Mvc.AjaxOnlyAttribute'. Derived types must either match the security accessibility of the base type or be less accessible.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It has moved to Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Futures. https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Futures/5.0.0